# Refresh page after login from login screen

Tags: php, authentication, redirect

Similar threads have been unhelpful.
Users must login to see our content.
To login from a restricted page they click "Login" which takes them to the wp login page. After successful login they are redirected to the home page when from desktop.

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Get last page URL visited in WordPress
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

//
add_action( 'wp', 'get_before_login_url' );
function get_before_login_url(){
    if( !is_user_logged_in() ):
    $_SESSION['referer_url'] = get_the_permalink();
    endif;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Redirect user to last URL in variable after login
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

//
/*@ After successful login redirect */
if( !function_exists('after_login_redirect') ):
    function after_login_redirect() {
 
    $redirect_url = home_url('/');
    if ( isset($_SESSION['referer_url']) ):
        $redirect_url = $_SESSION['referer_url'];
        unset( $_SESSION['referer_url'] );
    endif;
 
    return $redirect_url;
    exit;
   }
   add_filter('login_redirect', 'after_login_redirect');
endif;

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

The above snippet works fine from mobile, but clicking login from a desktop, then successfully logging in redirects the user to home. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you starting the session?

Answer (score 0):

It may work differently with the browser interface. Not sure what else is in your theme, but you may have to handle the init and destroy of the session itself to make $_SESSION available.

```
function session_init() {
  if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'session_init' );


function session_destroy() {
  session_destroy();
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'session_destroy');
```